# How to setup standardjs to work with flow?

Tags: javascript, standardjs

I am using standardjs.com ("standard": "10.0.3") and flow ("flow-bin": "0.54.1")

I need to make sure standardjs recognizie as valid code with flow annotation example:

```
export const find = (query: string):string => `${apiUrl}find?q=${query}&APPID=${apiKey}`
```

Currently I am reeving error:

```
 Parsing error: Unexpected token :
```

I have tried to use this package:

```
"standard-flow":"1.0.0"
```

with no success.

I would like to know how to setup standardjs properly to work with flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using two different dependencies:

```
"eslint-config-standard":"10.2.1",
"eslint-config-standard-flow": "1.0.1"
```

and configure standard ad:

```
"standard": {
    "env": [
      "jest"
    ],
    "globals": [
      "fetch",
      "test",
      "expect"
    ],
    "ignore":[
      "flow-typed"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "flowtype"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
```